# Не работает программа, хотя вроде правильная

Tags: c++, указатели, структуры, динамические-массивы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;
struct Train
{
    int number;
    char *Location[100];
    char *departure[10];
};
Train* AddStruct(Train* Obj, const int number);
void input(Train* Obj, const int number);
void show(const Train* Obj, const int number);
int main()
{
    Train *City;
    int n;
    int count = 0;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0;i < n;i++)
        {
            input(City,count);
            count++;
        }
    show(City, count);
    delete[] City;
    return 0;
}
Train* AddStruct(Train* Obj, const int number)
{
    if (number == 0)
    {    
        Obj = new Train[number + 1];
    }
    else
    {
        Train* tempObj = new Train[number + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            tempObj[i] = Obj[i];
        }
        delete[] Obj;
        Obj = tempObj;
    }
    return Obj;
}
void input(Train* Obj, const int number)
{
    cin >> Obj[number].number;
    cin >> *Obj[number].Location;
    cin >> *Obj[number].departure;
}
void show(const Train* Obj, const int number)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        cout << Obj[i].number << '\t' << Obj[i].Location << '\t' <<   Obj[i].departure << endl;
    }
}
```

Не могу понять почему програ ломается. Буду рад любой помощи. PS я еще новичек.

Comment: Что именно происходит надо угадать, да?

Comment: Она ломается после того когда я ввожу cin >> Obj[number].number;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Имеется несколько проблем в программе.

Во-первых, вы не выделили память для массива объектов типа `Train`. Указатель `City` не инициализирован и имеет неопределенное значение.

```
Train *City;
^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Поэтому при использовании этого указателя в данной функции

```
void input(Train* Obj, const int number)
{
    cin >> Obj[number].number;
    cin >> *Obj[number].Location;
    cin >> *Obj[number].departure;
}
```

ведет к неопределенному поведению программы.

Но даже если бы вы выделили массив и данный указатель был инициализирован адресом первого элемента массива, тем не менее программа неверная, так как в этих предложениях вышеуказанной функции

```
    cin >> *Obj[number].Location;
    cin >> *Obj[number].departure;
```

вы пытаетесь использовать также неинициализированные указатели  `Obj[number].Location` и `Obj[number].departure`.

Объявление этих полей структуры в том виде, как они представлены

```
struct Train
{
    int number;
    char *Location[100];
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    char *departure[10];
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

не имеют смысла. Вы объявили массивы из указателей типа `char *` вместо того, чтобы объявить массивы из объектов типа `char`. Я думаю, вы имели в виду следующее объявление

```
struct Train
{
    int number;
    char Location[100];
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    char departure[10];
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

Так как в функции `AddStruct` вы удаляете массив, адресуемый первым параметром,

```
Train* AddStruct(Train* Obj, const int number)
{
    if (number == 0)
    {    
        Obj = new Train[number + 1];
    }
    else
    {
        Train* tempObj = new Train[number + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            tempObj[i] = Obj[i];
        }
        delete[] Obj;
        Obj = tempObj;
    }
    return Obj;
}
```

то при ее вызове следует не забыть назначить возвращаемое значение указателю, который был передан функции в качестве аргумента. Например,

```
City = AddStruct( City, count );
```

Это не совсем ясный интуитивно интерфейс. Пользователь этой функции может забыть присвоить результат работы функции тому же самому указателю, который использовался в качестве аргумента.

Второе замечание к функции состоит в том, что не следует раздеять два случая в функции, когда параметр `number` равен 0 или не равен 0. Если параметр `number` равен 0, то в этом случае первый параметр должен быть равен `nullptr`, а потому можно также и в этом случае применить к этому указателю оператор `delete []`.

Исходя из сказанного, я бы объявил эту фукцию следующим образом.

```
int AddStruct( Train * &Obj, int number )
{
    Train* tempObj = new Train[number + 1];

    for ( int i = 0; i < number; i++ )
    {
        tempObj[i] = Obj[i];
    }

    delete [] Obj;

    Obj = tempObj;

    return number + 1;
}
```

EDIT: С учетом вами сказанного в комментариях программа может выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>

struct Train
{
    unsigned int number;
    char *location;
    char *departure;
};

const size_t LOCATION_LENGTH  = 100;
const size_t DEPARTURE_LENGTH = 10;

size_t AddStruct( Train * &trains, size_t n );
void Input( Train *trains, size_t i );
void Show( const Train *trians, size_t n );
void Free( Train * &trains, size_t n );

int main() 
{
    Train *city = nullptr;

    std::cout << "Enter number of trains: ";
    size_t n = 0;

    std::cin >> n;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        AddStruct( city, i );
        Input( city, i );
    }

    Show( city, n );

    Free( city, n );

    return 0;
}

size_t AddStruct( Train * &trains, size_t n )
{
    Train *tmp = new Train[ n + 1 ]();

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) tmp[i] = trains[i];

    delete [] trains;

    trains = tmp;

    return n + 1;
}

void Input( Train *trains, size_t i )
{
    std::cout << "Enter number of train #" << i + 1 << ": ";

    std::cin >> trains[i].number;

    std::cout << "Enter location for train #" << i + 1 << ": ";

    trains[i].location = new char[LOCATION_LENGTH];

    std::cin.ignore( 1, '\n' );
    std::cin.getline( trains[i].location, LOCATION_LENGTH );

    std::cout << "Enter departure for train #" << i + 1 << ": ";

    trains[i].departure = new char[DEPARTURE_LENGTH];

    std::cin.getline( trains[i].departure, DEPARTURE_LENGTH );
}

void Show( const Train *trains, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i <n; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << "Number: "    << trains[i].number << '\n';
        std::cout << "Location: "  << trains[i].location << '\n';
        std::cout << "Departure: " << trains[i].departure << '\n';

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void Free( Train * &trains, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        delete [] trains[i].location;
        delete [] trains[i].departure;
    }

    delete [] trains;

    trains = nullptr;
}
```

Диалог пользователя с программой может быть, к примеру, таким

```
Enter number of trains: 3

Enter number of train #1: 1
Enter location for train #1: A
Enter departure for train #1: A1
Enter number of train #2: 2
Enter location for train #2: B
Enter departure for train #2: B2
Enter number of train #3: 3
Enter location for train #3: C
Enter departure for train #3: C3
Number: 1
Location: A
Departure: A1

Number: 2
Location: B
Departure: B2

Number: 3
Location: C
Departure: C3
```

Вы можете модифицировать ее по своему усмотрению.

Comment: Благодарю, теперь не ломается. Вопрос, а как можно инициализировать ввод если перед Location и departure * ?

Comment: @KairatAmanzharov Я не понял вашего вопроса.

Comment: Простите, я имел ввиду если мне по заданию нужно использовать `char*` [ссылка](http://contester.iitu.kz:9006/ru/problem-pid-c3c5?ps=1&smt=a&smpwid=0)

Comment: @KairatAmanzharov Вы имеете в виду, что поля Location и departure должны иметь объявления char *? В этом случае при вводе значений вам сначала надо будет выделить память, на которую эти указатели будут указывать. Например, City[i].Location = new char[199]; и лишь только затем туда читать данные из потока. Вы также должны не забыть освободить эту память. Либо вы в цикле освобождаете для каждого элемента эту память для этих полей,, либо вам следует написать деструктор для вашей структуры.

Answer (score 2):

```
Train *City;
/* ... */
for (int i = 0;i < n;i++) {
    input(City,count);
```

Первая ошибка здесь, дальше смотреть смысла нет. Память под `City` не выделена, вот и валится всё. Не говоря уж о том, что происходит этим указателем в функции `input()`. Но это уже совсем другая история.